# Facebook sharing on app doesn't work

Tags: facebook, ipad, ios8, share

I use social framework for Facebook and Twitter sharing integration into app. On the iPad Air iOS 8.1 it doesn't work for Facebook.

```
-(IBAction)Facebook:(id)sender{

if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
    SLComposeViewController *FACEBOOK = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];


    [FACEBOOK setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wow, look at my new high score!"];

     [self presentViewController:FACEBOOK animated:YES completion:nil];

}
else{

    UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"FaceBook Signed Out" message:@"Add or create Facebook account in Settings." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

}

 }
```

For the above iPad Air iOS 8.1, nothing at all appears in shared message.

However, for iPad non-retina iOS 8.1.2, the above code works fine and message appears in shared message.

What's going on? Even the signed out message doesn't appear as I stated in code for iPad Air iOS 8.1. Why isn't it working on all iOS 8's or is this an iPad Retina issue?

Comment: This is a known issue. `setInitialText:` will not work when the Facebook application is installed.  `addURL:` does work though if you'd like to add a link.

Comment: The URL part works but setInitialText isn't working. However, setInitialText is only not working on my iPad Air iOS 8.1. It works on every other iPhone/iPad device.

I have Facebook app installed on all devices iPhone 6, iPhone 5, iPad non-retina, iPhone 4s. setInitialText works there but not iPad Air iOS 8.1

Answer (score 1):

Any form is prefilling is not allowed, as stated in the [policy](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill). Previously it was still possible using `setInitialText`, but recently this has been also been enforced on the software side. Any values provided here are not used in the dialog.

In this case, it's actually a bug (or limitation of the platform) that it is still working on the non-retine iOS 8.1.2 iPad. Please don't rely on this; in a next update this might also become enforced through software.